# How to display the point value in the line chart stroke of google api area chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, area

I need to display the point value in my area chart. I found how to do it in the line chart but not the area chart. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: you can add annotations to any of the charts in the `'corecharts'` package, including `AreaChart`, using the [annotation column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole)...

Comment: I saw that but not sure how that can be implemented for the AreaChart.

My data looks like this:

`["Month","2018","2019","2020"],
["Jan",30.4,24.9,26],
["Feb",30.5,27.6,25.4],
["Mar",30.7,27.2,26.1],
["Apr",28.7,26.1,24.7],
["May",32.8,25.9,28.6],
["Jun",27.5,27.3,26],
["Jul",27.9,26.2,27.1],
["Aug",27.1,27.1,27],
["Sep",27.1,27.1,27],
["Oct",28.1,25.2,24.4],
["Nov",26.5,27.3,26.7],
["Dec",26.9,25.2,0]

I need the annotation for all the data, not just one column.

Comment: I need the annotation for all the data, not just one column.

I don't have:
`data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});

                    data.addRows([
                        ['2008', 23, 23]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the annotation column should follow each series column that should be displayed,
as follows...

```
["Month", "2018", {type: "string", role: "annotation"}, "2019", {type: "string", role: "annotation"}, "2020", {type: "string', role: "annotation"}],
["Jan", 30.4, "30.4", 24.9, "24.9", 26, "26"],
```